# Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm learning React-Redux, and I'm trying to build an app in which I write an input called `trial` in LIST CREATION, insert it in `list` and through the function `updateList` update the initial state of `list` in the REDUCER, and then display that list in the TRIALLIST screen, since nothing really happened when I launched the code, I've put a console.log in the INDEX.JS and it returns the error `Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.`, I've tried googling it but I could not seem to find a solution. Thank you in advance for your help.

**LIST CREATION**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateList } from '../../../../../redux/actions/index.js';


class trial extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      trial: '',
      list: [],
        };
  }

submitTrial(){
    let list = this.state.list;
    list.push(this.state.trial);
    this.props.updateList(list);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("TrialList");
  }

 render() {    
    return (

            <Button transparent>
              <Icon
                name="checkmark"
                onPress={() =>  this.submitTrial()}
              />
            </Button>

           <TextInput
             placeholder='type here'
             onChangeText={(trial) => this.setState({ trial })}
           />


const mapDispatchToProps = { updateList };

export default connect( mapDispatchToProps )( trial );
```

**TRIALLIST**

```
class TrialList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: this.props.list,
    };
  }

  

  render() {
    return (

     <FlatList
            data={this.state.list}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (

                    //some data ///

      />



 function mapStateToProps(store){
  return{
      list: store.userState.list
   };
  }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrialList);
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
import { ADD_LIST } from "../constants/index";

export const updateList = (list) => {
  return console.log({ type: ADD_LIST, payload: list}) <----------------------HERE
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, ADD_LIST } from "../constants";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  list: [],
};



export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
        return {
          ...state,
          currentUser: action.currentUser,
        };
      case ADD_LIST: 
      return{
        ...state,
        list: [...action.payload],
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
  
};
```

**APP.JS**

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export class App extends React.Component {

render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <TrialList/>
          <trial/>
        <Provide/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you returning console.log here?

```
export const updateList = (list) => {
  return console.log({ type: ADD_LIST, payload: list}) <----------------------HERE
}
```

console.log returns `undefined`, and, if you want to log the action triggered, then, console.log it first and then return the object like this.

```
export const updateList = (list) => {
  console.log({ type: ADD_LIST, payload: list}) <----------------------HERE
  return { type: ADD_LIST, payload: list}
}
```

Comment: Even when removing the log, the app would just not work, I don’t really know what I’m doing wrong, I’ve started programming a few months ago, and Redux drove me crazy.

Comment: okay, and what is the error now? after resolving the console.log.

Comment: I don't know why, it seems to be solved, maybe I typed something wrong, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
export const updateList = (list) => ({
  type: ADD_LIST, payload: list 
})
```

You are missing the parenthesis around after the arrow and before closing the function body.

Comment: you don't need the parenthesis if you have `return` like op has. doing it your way is just shorthand to avoid the return.